# Mostrar resultados mysql indiferente al carrito de compra

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy creando un sistema de carro de la compra, que funciona todo muy bien, ahora el problema viene donde muestra los resultados del carro (`cesta.php`), quiero mostrar resultados indiferente a lo que el usuario haya insertado al carro, para así facilitar si desea comprar mas productos.

Digamos si añadimos 3 productos para comprar, con `id1`, `id2`, `id3`.

Y en la Base de datos (`productos`) existen 6 registros.

Pues deberia mostrar `id4`, `id5`, `id6`, ya que como he mencionado antes, el usuario ya a insertado para comprar el `id1`, `id2`, `id3`.

El carro de la compra la guardo en una sesión de la siguiente manera:

El carro de la compra la creo en la página `card.php`

```
 //Carro de la compra

//Si esta definida la ID obtenido por URL
if (isset($_GET['articulo'])) {

    $id_tutorial = $_GET['articulo'];//Obtenemos el ID del tutorial añadido, para poder acer comprobaciones a mostrar otros resultados.

    //Si esta definido la sesion carro -> es decir si ay algun articulo comprado
    if (isset($_SESSION['carrito'])) {

        $arreglo = $_SESSION['carrito'];
        $encontro = false;      

        for ($i=0; $i<count($arreglo); $i++) { 

            if ($arreglo[$i]['Id'] == $_GET['articulo']) {
                $encontro = true;               
            }
        }

        if ($encontro == false) {


            $titulo = "";
            $precio = 0;
            $precioUSD = 0;
            $icon = "";

            $stmt = $c->prepare("SELECT titulo,precio,icon,id_autor FROM tutoriales WHERE page=? and status=1");
            $stmt->bind_param("i",$_GET['articulo']);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->store_result();
            if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
                $stmt->bind_result($titulo,$precio,$icon,$id_autor);
                while ($stmt->fetch()) {

                    //Sentencia prepare -> autor proyecto
                    $stmtN = $c->prepare("SELECT autor FROM autor WHERE id_autor=?");           
                    $stmtN->bind_param("i", $id_autor);         
                    $stmtN->execute();          
                    $stmtN->bind_result($autor);            
                    $stmtN->fetch();            
                    $stmtN->close();

                    $datosnuevos = array('Id' => $_GET['articulo'], 'Titulo' => $titulo, 'Precio' => $precio, 'Icon' => $icon, 'Cantidad' => 1 );

                    /*
                        #Si se utiliza array_push() para añadir un solo elemento al array, es mejor utilizar $array[] = ya que de esta forma no existe la sobrecarga de llamar a una función. 
                    */

                    //array_push($arreglo, $datosnuevos); 
                    $arreglo[] = $datosnuevos;
                    $_SESSION['carrito'] = $arreglo;

                    $data = $_SESSION['carrito'];
                    $value_carrito = count($data);
                    $_SESSION['compras'] = $value_carrito;

                } $stmt->close();


            } else {
                $stmt->close();
            }
        }   

    } else { //Caso falso añadimos primer articulo al carro

        $titulo = "";
        $precio = 0;
        $precioUSD = 0;
        $icon = "";

        $stmt = $c->prepare("SELECT titulo,precio,icon,id_autor FROM tutoriales WHERE page=? and status=1");
        $stmt->bind_param("i",$_GET['articulo']);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
            $stmt->bind_result($titulo,$precio,$icon,$id_autor);
            while ($stmt->fetch()) {

                //Sentencia prepare -> autor proyecto
                $stmtN = $c->prepare("SELECT autor FROM autor WHERE id_autor=?");           
                $stmtN->bind_param("i", $id_autor);         
                $stmtN->execute();          
                $stmtN->bind_result($autor);            
                $stmtN->fetch();            
                $stmtN->close();

            } $stmt->close();

        } else {
            $stmt->close();
        }       

            $arreglo[] = array('Id' => $_GET['articulo'], 'Titulo' => $titulo, 'Precio' => $precio, 'Icon' => $icon, 'Cantidad' => 1 );

            $_SESSION['carrito'] = $arreglo;

            $data = $_SESSION['carrito'];
            $value_carrito = count($data);
            $_SESSION['compras'] = $value_carrito;

            //echo "<script>window.location.reload();</script>";


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voy a autocontestarme a mi prejunta, ya que me ayudaron en `Stack Overflow`.

Este ejemplo dará una ventaja inicial sobre cómo construir la consulta `SELECT`:

- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e26d17/1

Supongamos `$_SESSION['carrito']` contiene los productos que ya han sido comprados por el cliente y `$_SESSION[ 'compras']` mantiene el recuento del número total de productos adquiridos, la consulta `SELECT` para recuperar los productos restantes sería así:

```
SELECT id_tutorial,page,titulo,info,icon,bg,vdo,url,precio,duracion,status,id_nivel,id_estado 
FROM tutoriales 
WHERE status = 1 AND id_tutorial NOT IN (
    SELECT id_tutorial 
    FROM tutoriales 
    WHERE id_tutorial IN (" . rtrim(str_repeat("?,", $_SESSION['compras']), ",") . "
    )
)
```

Y el codigo deberia ser así:

```
$param = array(); 
$paramType = '';
for($i = 0; $i < $_SESSION['compras']; ++$i){
    switch(gettype($_SESSION['carrito'][$i]['Id'])){
        case 'boolean':
        case 'NULL':
        case 'integer':
            $paramType .= 'i';
            break;
        case 'double':
            $paramType .= 'd';
            break;
        case 'string':
            $paramType .= 's';
            break;
        default:
            $paramType .= 'b';
    }
    $param[] = &$_SESSION['carrito'][$i]['Id'];
}
array_unshift($param, $paramType);
call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $param);

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
    $result->bind_result($id_tutorial,$page,$titulo,$info,$icon,$bg,$vdo,$url,$precio,$duracion,$status,$id_nivel,$id_estado);
    while ($result->fetch()){

        // your code          

    }
} else {
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Implemente el ejemplo en mi servidor y funciona correctamente.
Tambien os dejo la entrada de `Stack Overflow`, donde me contestaron:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39946531/how-to-show-related-products-to-the-shopping-cart-products