# mysqli_fetch_assoc en estilo orientado a objetos

Tags: php, mysqli

Estoy obteniendo valores desde un asociativo `array`

```
  $datos = "";
  $array = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
  foreach ($array as $valor => $dato) {
    $datos = $datos . $dato . ",";
  }

  $app = rtrim($datos, ",");
  echo $app;
```

Resultado: 1,2,3,4

Ahora es extraño no comprendo que esta sucediendo en un procedimiento en estilo orientado a objetos en MySQLi solo me muestra un resultado y lo demás los ignora.

```
  $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT id, notice, tag FROM news WHERE id in (?)");
  $stmt->bind_param('i',$app);
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->store_result();
  $stmt->bind_result($id, $notice, $tag);

  while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo '<div class="content-notice">
             <h1>'.$notice.'</h1>
             <span>'.$tag.'</span>
         </div>';
  }
```

He probado cambiando de entero `(i)` por `string` `(s)` pero da el mismo resultado solo muestra un resultado...

En cambio en un procedimiento distinto sin orientado a objeto ahí si me imprime los 4 resultados.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM news WHERE id in ({$app})";
$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    echo '<h1>'.$row['notice'].'</h1>';
}
```

Me pueden explicar que esta sucediendo?

Comment: No lose seguro pero quizás el error se produce porque solo pasas un tipo en tu `bind_param` y realmente son 4 parámetros diferentes, es decir, lógicamente sería algo así: `bind_param("i",1,2,3,4);`, que no estaría correcto, quizás te funciona esto `bind_param("iiii",$app);`

Comment: @D.Bulten Son datos generados automáticamente  desde un `array` o desde un `foreach` eso no puedo controlarlo es decir pueden ser `1` `3` `10` etc...

Comment: Aquí estamos ante uno de los casos más *penosos* del uso de mysqli con respecto a PDO. Supongo que en `$app` tienes una lista de valores tales que: `1,4,6,...n`. Pues bien, tendrás que recurrir a procedimientos nada evidentes para: 1º. Crear un array con los valores de `$app` (si ya son un array entonces perfecto, lo usamos tal cual)..., 2º, Contar los valores del array y luego crear una cadena de `?`, 3º. Ingeniarte cómo bindear de forma dinámica los signos de `?` y los  valores al statement. Si me dices lo que hay por ejemplo en `$app` podría *aventurarme*  a una respuesta.

Comment: @A.Cedano el `$app` contiene los `$id` único de las noticias que se guardan mediante una `session` y desde esa `session` voy obteniendo los `id` de las noticias.

Comment: @A.Cedano pero como en **ideone** no puedo dar ejemplos en vivo lo realice de esa manera https://ideone.com/1uoTVG pero el procedimiento es igual es decir del `foreach` + el `rtrim` igual a `$app` obtengo estos resultados `1,2,3,4...`

Comment: Si lose, tuve un mismo problema, por eso te digo que el fallo es porque los parámetros van variando, y solo pasas un tipo, deberían de coincidir siempre, te dejo un respuesta que me dieron que me funciona https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/26489/mostrar-resultados-mysql-indiferente-al-carrito-de-compra, otra cosa podrías quitar las líneas de tu `foreach` y tu `trim` y hacer directo esto `$app = implode(",", $array);`

Comment: @D.Bulten aquí hay algo que aún no entiendo hice el procedimiento manualmente como lo mencionaste como por curiosidad `bind_param("iiii", $app)`; pero me muestra este error: `Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables in C:\xampp\htdocs\array\index.php on line 16` les cambie de `i` por `s` también añadí más `????` pero nada...

Comment: @A.Cedano Si ya es un `array` de aquí ya sale más cosas que no comprendo: ***contar los valores del array, crear una cadena de `?` (esto se ve complicado ´?´)*** *PERO no olvide que ya los hice manualmente pero no funciono si va hacer el mismo resultado que lo hice manualmente funcionara?*

Comment: Fíjate en el enlace la respuesta que me dejaron en SO, a mí me funciono perfecto, quizás te funciona también, lo único que en mi caso era una sesión de compras con el id de compra: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39946531/how-to-show-related-products-to-the-shopping-cart-products, en cambio si haces esto en tu sentencia preparada `$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT id, notice, tag FROM news WHERE id IN ( ".implode(",",$array)." ) ");` y quitas tu `bind_param` también te funcionara.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oscar prueba este código.

- `$arrIN` es un array con los ids que quieres usar como criterio en el `IN...`
- A partir de ese array se crearán los marcadores de posición `?` que llevará la consulta preparada.
- También se creará una cadena `$strTipos` con los tipos de datos para cada uno, en este caso asumo que son del tipo entero, por eso la `i`.
- Usaremos el operador de los tres puntos (PHP 5.6+), llamado [Lista de argumentos de longitud variable](http://php.net/manual/es/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list) para hacer el binding dinámico de cada tipo y su respectivo valor.

El código quedaría más o menos así:

```
$arrIN=array(1,2,3,4); //Cámbialo por tu array. DEBE SER UN ARRAY
$strMarcas  = str_repeat('?,', count($arrIN) - 1) . '?';
$strTipos = str_repeat('i', count($arrIN));
$strSQL="SELECT id, notice, tag FROM news WHERE id in ($strMarcas)"; //Ningún peligro de Inyección aquí... :)

$stmt=$con->prepare($strSQL);

$stmt->bind_param($strTipos, ...$arrIN);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($id, $notice, $tag);

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo '<div class="content-notice">
             <h1>'.$notice.'</h1>
             <span>'.$tag.'</span>
         </div>';
}
```

---

Mi recomendación final es pasar a PDO. Todo este rollo es debido a una sola cosa, **¡mysqli no admite que se pasen los parámetros directamente en el `execute`!** Con PDO esto se habría resuelto con una o dos líneas de código. Sin embargo, fíjate todas las vueltas que hay que dar con `mysqli`.

Puedes leer al respecto este interesante artículo publicado en phpdelusions.net: ***[Why mysqli prepared statemens are so hard to use?](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/wtf)*** - (*¿Por qué las consultas preparadas son tan difíciles de usar en mysqli?*)

Comment: Prometo ponerlo en práctica cuando culminé de realizar esta aplicación, gracias por la sugerencias :) ***tengo curiosidad de cómo se solucionaría con dos líneas puedes publicarla en la respuesta o en ideone para tenerlo como referencia a futuro*** :) saludos!

Comment: @Oscar si usáramos PDO, sería: **(1)**. Obtener los marcadores de posición como hacemos aquí: `$strMarcas  = str_repeat('?,', count($arrIN) - 1) . '?';` y **(2)**. Pasar el array de valores directamente en el método execute:  `$stmt->execute($arrIN);`. Toda la cuestión dificultosa del `bind_param` y las dichosas `i`, `s`, `d`... quedan atrás, no hacen falta. Y menos mal que desde PHP 5.6+ podemos hacerlo de una forma algo más elegante, antes de PHP 5.6 el asunto era aún más complicado y oscuro. Luego, la forma de leer los resultados en PDO es mucho más fácil. Creo que esto sería tema aparte.

Comment: Sí es verdad es tema aparte, en cierta parte es bueno aprender las dificultades de las consultas preparadas `mysqli` muy bien explicado... también la referencia del enlace que has enlazado, suena muy interesante todo esto de `PDO` estoy entusiasmado lo pondré en practica lo más pronto! Buen día :)