# Alternativa a la función money_format() en PHP en plataforma Windows

Tags: php

Ya se han solucionado problemas como el de [¿Cómo obtener un arreglo asociativo usando consultas preparadas con mysqli?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/114051/c%C3%B3mo-obtener-un-arreglo-asociativo-usando-consultas-preparadas-con-mysqli/128148#128148) cuando este sólo esta disponible con `mysqlnd`.

No entiendo porque las complicaciones de `PHP` de crear funciones que no están disponible si no tienen instalado controladores o librerías, se supones que si se tiene instalado un servidor `apache` debería funcionar como tal.

Veamos el siguiente uso requiere tener la extensión [Intl](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php) para poder usar:

- [NumberFormatter :: formatCurrency](https://www.php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.formatcurrency.php) - Formatea un valor de moneda de acuerdo con las reglas del formateador.

Ejemplo:

```
$amount = '12345.67';
$formatter = new NumberFormatter('en_GB',  NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
echo 'UK: ', $formatter->formatCurrency($amount, 'EUR'), PHP_EOL;
$formatter = new NumberFormatter('de_DE',  NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
echo 'DE: ', $formatter->formatCurrency($amount, 'EUR'), PHP_EOL;
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'NumberFormatter' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\Edition\formatodemoneda.php:4 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown

Y por último la función `money_format()` sólo está definida si el sistema tiene capacidad `strfmon`. Por ejemplo, `Windows` no lo hace, así que `money_format()` no está definido en `Windows`.

Ejemplo

```
$number = 1234.56;

// let's print the international format for the en_US locale
setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US');
echo money_format('%i', $number) . "\n";
// USD 1,234.56
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function money_format() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Edition\formatodemoneda.php:21 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown

En algunas preguntas similares en StackOcerflow Ingles, se observa que se trata de crear funciones dependientes para el tipo de monedad por ejemplo una [función para el formato de moneda india](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9974704/defining-cross-platform-money-format-function-linux-and-windows), entre [otros intentos fallidos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139793/unformat-money-when-parsing-in-php). Pero si existen varias monedas, no me parece una solución agregar tantas funciones para cada tipo de moneda.

Hasta que encontré esta pregunta [Alternative to money_format() Function in PHP on Windows Platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6369887/alternative-to-money-format-function-in-php-on-windows-platform) con una respuesta muy curiosa que seguro se podría usar como referencia para crear una solución como la de `mysqlnd` o toca resignarse a dar formatos mediante [`number-format`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) .

```
function money_format($floatcurr, $curr = 'EUR'){
    $currencies['ARS'] = array(2, ',', '.');          //  Argentine Peso
    $currencies['AMD'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Armenian Dram
    $currencies['AWG'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Aruban Guilder
    $currencies['AUD'] = array(2, '.', ' ');          //  Australian Dollar
    $currencies['BSD'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Bahamian Dollar
    $currencies['BHD'] = array(3, '.', ',');          //  Bahraini Dinar
    $currencies['BDT'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Bangladesh, Taka
    $currencies['BZD'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Belize Dollar
    $currencies['BMD'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Bermudian Dollar
    $currencies['BOB'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Bolivia, Boliviano
    $currencies['BAM'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Bosnia and Herzegovina, Convertible Marks
    $currencies['BWP'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Botswana, Pula
    $currencies['BRL'] = array(2, ',', '.');          //  Brazilian Real
    $currencies['BND'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Brunei Dollar
    $currencies['CAD'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Canadian Dollar
    $currencies['KYD'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Cayman Islands Dollar
    $currencies['CLP'] = array(0,  '', '.');          //  Chilean Peso
    $currencies['CNY'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  China Yuan Renminbi
    $currencies['COP'] = array(2, ',', '.');          //  Colombian Peso
    $currencies['CRC'] = array(2, ',', '.');          //  Costa Rican Colon
    $currencies['HRK'] = array(2, ',', '.');          //  Croatian Kuna
    $currencies['CUC'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Cuban Convertible Peso
    $currencies['CUP'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Cuban Peso
    $currencies['CYP'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Cyprus Pound
    $currencies['CZK'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Czech Koruna
    $currencies['DKK'] = array(2, ',', '.');          //  Danish Krone
    $currencies['DOP'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Dominican Peso
    $currencies['XCD'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  East Caribbean Dollar
    $currencies['EGP'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Egyptian Pound
    $currencies['SVC'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  El Salvador Colon
    $currencies['ATS'] = array(2, ',', '.');          //  Euro
    $currencies['BEF'] = array(2, ',', '.');          //  Euro
    $currencies['DEM'] = array(2, ',', '.');          //  Euro
    $currencies['EEK'] = array(2, ',', '.');          //  Euro
    $currencies['ESP'] = array(2, ',', '.');          //  Euro
    $currencies['EUR'] = array(2, ',', '.');          //  Euro
    $currencies['FIM'] = array(2, ',', '.');          //  Euro
    $currencies['FRF'] = array(2, ',', '.');          //  Euro
    $currencies['GRD'] = array(2, ',', '.');          //  Euro
    $currencies['IEP'] = array(2, ',', '.');          //  Euro
    $currencies['ITL'] = array(2, ',', '.');          //  Euro
    $currencies['LUF'] = array(2, ',', '.');          //  Euro
    $currencies['NLG'] = array(2, ',', '.');          //  Euro
    $currencies['PTE'] = array(2, ',', '.');          //  Euro
    $currencies['GHC'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Ghana, Cedi
    $currencies['GIP'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Gibraltar Pound
    $currencies['GTQ'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Guatemala, Quetzal
    $currencies['HNL'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Honduras, Lempira
    $currencies['HKD'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Hong Kong Dollar
    $currencies['HUF'] = array(0,  '', '.');          //  Hungary, Forint
    $currencies['ISK'] = array(0,  '', '.');          //  Iceland Krona
    $currencies['INR'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Indian Rupee
    $currencies['IDR'] = array(2, ',', '.');          //  Indonesia, Rupiah
    $currencies['IRR'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Iranian Rial
    $currencies['JMD'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Jamaican Dollar
    $currencies['JPY'] = array(0,  '', ',');          //  Japan, Yen
    $currencies['JOD'] = array(3, '.', ',');          //  Jordanian Dinar
    $currencies['KES'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Kenyan Shilling
    $currencies['KWD'] = array(3, '.', ',');          //  Kuwaiti Dinar
    $currencies['LVL'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Latvian Lats
    $currencies['LBP'] = array(0,  '', ' ');          //  Lebanese Pound
    $currencies['LTL'] = array(2, ',', ' ');          //  Lithuanian Litas
    $currencies['MKD'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Macedonia, Denar
    $currencies['MYR'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Malaysian Ringgit
    $currencies['MTL'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Maltese Lira
    $currencies['MUR'] = array(0,  '', ',');          //  Mauritius Rupee
    $currencies['MXN'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Mexican Peso
    $currencies['MZM'] = array(2, ',', '.');          //  Mozambique Metical
    $currencies['NPR'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Nepalese Rupee
    $currencies['ANG'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Netherlands Antillian Guilder
    $currencies['ILS'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  New Israeli Shekel
    $currencies['TRY'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  New Turkish Lira
    $currencies['NZD'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  New Zealand Dollar
    $currencies['NOK'] = array(2, ',', '.');          //  Norwegian Krone
    $currencies['PKR'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Pakistan Rupee
    $currencies['PEN'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Peru, Nuevo Sol
    $currencies['UYU'] = array(2, ',', '.');          //  Peso Uruguayo
    $currencies['PHP'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Philippine Peso
    $currencies['PLN'] = array(2, '.', ' ');          //  Poland, Zloty
    $currencies['GBP'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Pound Sterling
    $currencies['OMR'] = array(3, '.', ',');          //  Rial Omani
    $currencies['RON'] = array(2, ',', '.');          //  Romania, New Leu
    $currencies['ROL'] = array(2, ',', '.');          //  Romania, Old Leu
    $currencies['RUB'] = array(2, ',', '.');          //  Russian Ruble
    $currencies['SAR'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Saudi Riyal
    $currencies['SGD'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Singapore Dollar
    $currencies['SKK'] = array(2, ',', ' ');          //  Slovak Koruna
    $currencies['SIT'] = array(2, ',', '.');          //  Slovenia, Tolar
    $currencies['ZAR'] = array(2, '.', ' ');          //  South Africa, Rand
    $currencies['KRW'] = array(0,  '', ',');          //  South Korea, Won
    $currencies['SZL'] = array(2, '.', ', ');         //  Swaziland, Lilangeni
    $currencies['SEK'] = array(2, ',', '.');          //  Swedish Krona
    $currencies['CHF'] = array(2, '.', '\'');         //  Swiss Franc
    $currencies['TZS'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Tanzanian Shilling
    $currencies['THB'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Thailand, Baht
    $currencies['TOP'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  Tonga, Paanga
    $currencies['AED'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  UAE Dirham
    $currencies['UAH'] = array(2, ',', ' ');          //  Ukraine, Hryvnia
    $currencies['USD'] = array(2, '.', ',');          //  US Dollar
    $currencies['VUV'] = array(0,  '', ',');          //  Vanuatu, Vatu
    $currencies['VEF'] = array(2, ',', '.');          //  Venezuela Bolivares Fuertes
    $currencies['VEB'] = array(2, ',', '.');          //  Venezuela, Bolivar
    $currencies['VND'] = array(0,  '', '.');          //  Viet Nam, Dong
    $currencies['ZWD'] = array(2, '.', ' ');          //  Zimbabwe Dollar
    // custom function to generate: ##,##,###.##
    function formatinr($input)
    {
        $dec = "";
        $pos = strpos($input, ".");
        if ($pos === FALSE)
        {
            //no decimals
        }
        else
        {
            //decimals
            $dec   = substr(round(substr($input, $pos), 2), 1);
            $input = substr($input, 0, $pos);
        }
        $num   = substr($input, -3);    // get the last 3 digits
        $input = substr($input, 0, -3); // omit the last 3 digits already stored in $num
        // loop the process - further get digits 2 by 2
        while (strlen($input) > 0)
        {
            $num   = substr($input, -2).",".$num;
            $input = substr($input, 0, -2);
        }
        return $num.$dec;
    }
    if ($curr == "INR")
    {
        return formatinr($floatcurr);
    }
    else
    {
        return number_format($floatcurr, $currencies[$curr][0], $currencies[$curr][1], $currencies[$curr][2]);
    }
}
```

Comment: creo que te refieres a que quede como una [pregunta de wiki](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2180/puedo-crear-una-pregunta-wiki-de-comunidad) pues *wikipedia* es una plataforma aparte de lo que es SOI

Comment: @anonimo Sí, ya corregido me estoy olvidando de muchas cosas en StackOverflow, recientemente hoy he vuelto a preguntar dos preguntas, de igual forma he aportado a otras preguntas, no he tenido tiempo que necesito nuevamente leer todo sobre StackOverflow, Saludos!

Comment: Este enlace al GitHub de [gerardojbaez](https://github.com/gerardojbaez/money) y este [código](https://mymonkeydo.com/php-money_format-for-windows/) que remplaza la función parecen interesantes. Los dejo por aquí :D

Comment: Decir "*No entiendo porque las complicaciones de PHP de crear funciones que no están disponible si no tienen instalado controladores o librerías, se supones que si se tiene instalado un servidor apache debería funcionar como tal.*" sugiere un desconocimiento total del tema. Apache gestiona una cosa y php otra completamente diferente, frecuentemente los usamos juntos pero no es necesario. Lo mismo pasa con las librerías. Considero que deberías eliminar de la pregunta las divagaciones personales y dejar solo lo referente a la duda de creación de la función de dar formato.

Comment: @Fly Los servidores apache como el uso de XAMPP, no funciona dichas funciones en Windows y, las otro tampoco sino tienen librerías instaladas, pero la pregunta es interesante, muy bien planteada detallando todo, ideal para que a futuro quizás sea una referencia como la `fuction` que asimila o hace funcionar datos de `fetch_assoc` en mysqli en consultas preparadas. Y efectivamente se obtuvo una respuesta que quizás sea o no la mejor, pero es una buena alternativa a qué instalar o usar proyectos `GitHub` multiplataforma, para quienes no los gusta instalar librerías.

Comment: @Fly La respuesta aceptada puede ser una opción. Saludos!

Comment: @IniDesing.com, la respuesta es la misma que la sugerida por el OP (con una ligera modificación trivial)  pero yo me refería a que es irrelevante lo comentado sobre **si es apropiado que php necesite librerías (externas o propias) para realizar ciertas funciones**, me parece que eso  quedaría englobado en **basado mayoritariamente en opiniones**, cual no es deseable en SO. En definitiva, y como ya indiqué, solo quería decir que ciñera la pregunta al **problema concreto** que tenga con la programación de la función de formateo de moneda.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Una forma sencilla de decirle a la función `number_format` que tipo de formato generar es usar el operador de los tres puntos (PHP 5.6+), llamado [Lista de argumentos de longitud variable](https://www.php.net/manual/es/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list) o operador de [desempaquetado de argumentos](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.splat) (...) también usado de forma dinámica en un [`bind_param($variable, ...$array);`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/120370/mysqli-fetch-assoc-en-estilo-orientado-a-objetos).

Existe otra función llamada [`call_user_func_array()`](https://www.php.net/call_user_func_array) un ejemplo de uso:

```
#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294313/unpacking-an-array-of-arguments-in-php
call_user_func_array("range", $args);
```

Otras referencias en StackOverflow [¿Cuál es el significado de Tres puntos (...) en PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41124015/meaning-of-three-dot-in-php).

Y finalmente obtenemos cierta parte del código, y le decimos al función `number_format` que tipo de moneda generar mediante la variable `$curr`.

```
$price = 1000;
$curr = 'USD';

function moneyFormat($price,$curr) {
    $currencies['EUR'] = array(2, ',', '.');        // Euro
    $currencies['ESP'] = array(2, ',', '.');        // Euro
    $currencies['USD'] = array(2, '.', ',');        // US Dollar
    $currencies['COP'] = array(2, ',', '.');        // Colombian Peso
    $currencies['CLP'] = array(0,  '', '.');        // Chilean Peso

    return number_format($price, ...$currencies[$curr]);
}

$money = moneyFormat($price,$curr);
echo $money;
```

Otra forma de usar sin definir en la variable `$curr = 'USD';` el tipo de moneda es realizarlo desde nuestra función `moneyFormat` de esta manera:

```
$money = moneyFormat($price,$curr='COP');
echo $money;
```

Answer (score 0):

Efectivamente, primero para aclarar el por que PHP requiere otras librerias.

Por lo general un lenguaje de programacion incluye una serie de funciones y librerias basicas para el uso generico, pero otras son usadas de fuentes de terceros ( *no siempre compatibles con todos los sitemas operativos* )

En muchos casos no tiene sentido reimplementar la libreria en PHP puro en lugar de usar una solcuion solucion pre-existente o funcion del sistema operativo ( *ademas que no seria igual de optimo* ), por ejemplo: `ffmpeg` herramienta para tratar videos, para poder usar una funcion y trabajar con edicion de video es neceasrio que el sistema operativo del servidor tenga instalada esta herramienta o para gestionar correo IMAP es necesario instalar la extension `php5-imap`.

En muchos casos tambien al instalar el interprete o compilador del lenguaje este no instala paquetes o librerias que considera de uso poco freucente por lo que una alternativa es revisar la documentacion para validar si este no es una opcion de compilacion: Por ejemplo `php_zip` para poder usarlo es necesario compilar php usando el argumento `--enable-zip` https://www.php.net/manual/es/zip.installation.php

Para el caso de tu pregunta en especifico, las fechas son un tema polemico en cuestiones de tecnologia ya que tiene muchas representaciones y dependen de la configuracion del servidor, entiendo que metodos como `money_format` puedan contar con el uso de alguna funcion de sistema operativo para consultar cual es el configuracion regional del servidor.

**¿Por que Apache no me resuelve esto?**

Apache unicamente interactua con PHP como un servidor web el cual recibe las peticiones terceriza su ejecucion con PHP y retorna una respuesta al usuario, en versiones 7.x de PHP apache no es necesario, para no crear una dependencia dificil de romper entre el servidor web y el lenguaje es que este no provee librerias o dependencias complementarias, ademas que este escaparia al rol del mismo.

**¿Entonces que hago con formatCurrency?**

Por lo pronto efectivamente como comentas la soluciones que existen son:

- Implementar la funcion number_format e inyectarlo en toda aplicacion
  PHP con `auto_prepend_file` en **php.ini**
- Implementar manualmente la funcion como indicas ( Moneda por moneda ).
- Usar una alternativa multiplataforma https://github.com/gerardojbaez/money